# How do I get this MySQL query / PHP function to return a zero if nothing is found?

Tags: php, mysql

The following function queries my database to see how many losses a user has had- this works great as long as the user has had at least 1 `Loss` identified in the table as `L`.

```
    public function getTotalLosses($playerId){

        $returnValue = array();
        $sql = "SELECT player1_result, player2_result FROM `results` WHERE player1_id = '".$playerId."' AND player1_result = 'L' OR player2_id = '".$playerId."'AND player2_result = 'L'";

        $result = $this->conn->query($sql);

        if($result != null && (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1)){

        while($row = $result -> fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

           if(!empty($row)){

                $returnValue = mysqli_num_rows($result);
           }
        }

       return $returnValue;

  }

}
```

How do I amend the code so if nothing is returned, a `0` is put into $returnValue?

I have tried `if (empty($result)) { $returnValue = 0 }` and `if $result == null { $returnValue = 0 ; }`

But neither did anything - unless I put that bit of code in the wrong place...

Comment: You already have an empty array as a default value. So check for it.

Comment: `return empty($returnValue) ? 0 : $returnValue;`

Comment: Use `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`

Comment: @JeremyHarris So I did this: ` if($result == null) {
   return empty($returnValue) ? 0 : $returnValue;
  } `  underneath return $returnValue but it didn't work - I guess i went wrong somewhere

Comment: You don't need the `$result == null` check. Literally change that last line to what I suggested.

Comment: Yeah just figured that :) getting there - it now sends `null` into my array which is better than it crashing it.  I must be approaching it wrong as I need the 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To write correct condition you need to know what query() function returns ($this->conn->query()). As alternative variant I'd suggest to check number of selected rows:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) === 0) {
   $returnValue = 0;
}
```

Comment: Cheers, that did it.  I've never seen the use of === before

Comment: Double "==" condition compare variables disregarding type so you can find situations when '0' string is equal 0 integer. Triple "===" check if variables equal and has the same  type.